# moving columns responsivly with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a section that reads left to right in bootstrap step up. What I am trying to do is get the right section to appear ontop of the left one in mobile view. I attempted using the push/pull methods but they seem to just push my content off the page.

Here is what I have

```
 <div class="row process-page wow animated fadeInRightBig animation-delay-2"><!-- Create row col-6 -->
            <div class="col-xs-push-12 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <h3 class="title margin-b-30">Title</h3>
                <p>Content</p>
            </div> <!-- end col-6 -->
            <div class="col-xs-pull-12 col-md-6 col-sm-6 clipB" >
                <h3 class="title margin-b-30 margin-l-30"></h3>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- end Row -->
```

So it looks fine in large/medium, however mobile I cannot seem to get them to switch places (top to bottom)

Here is what I Mean

Desktop  :

```
  [A][B]
```

to mobile

```
 [B]
 [A]
```

I thought the push/pull would do the trick if i pushed the top one 12 and pulled the bottom one 12, but all it does it push them both off the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `push` and `pull` in the wrong way, you need to use that for the `sm` view. Try this:

- First change the order in HTML and then use right the push and pull

  ```
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">
          <p>B</p>
      </div> 
      <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6" >
        <p>A</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  ```

Check this [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/vBP5FTXDnz)

Answer (score 1):

Just push-12 means offsetting by that amount. Use pull-left and pull-right instead.